# Problem with mouse zoom in Open Layers 6

Tags: zoom, mouse-wheel, openlayers

I'm using latest version of OpenLayers 6 and I noticed that even in the official examples there is small problem (or it is a feature) with mouse zoom. When I set zoom restrictions then while using the zoom in/zoom out buttons I can't zoom more or zoom out according those restrictions. But with mouse wheel it behaves strange, the map is zoomed out (despite restrictions) and when you stop it comes back to its place.

Take a look here: https://www.screencast.com/t/P6skAIhl433V

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: To be able to zoom out so more than a world width is visible you need `multiWorld: true` set in the view options. See the documentation https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html

Comment: A would dare to call this a bug. I tested the code on an older version of ol6 (don't now exactly which, I think it's 6.1.1) and it does not behave this way. I can confirm this strange behaviour on version 6.2.1.

Comment: The overshoot and bounce back effect is due to the smoothExtentConstraint default.  Set `smoothExtentConstraint: false` in the view options to disable it.

Comment: @Mike So this default value changed lately or is this new functionality?

Comment: @TomazicM It was new in 6.0.0  multiWorld only applies to global projections.  Previously constraint options were set in the default interactions settings, not the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it using `smoothResolutionConstraint: false` set on the view.

Thanks @Mike for tip where to look for it!

Comment: Mike has not given just a tip, he gave you a complete answer.

Comment: @TomazicM No... He proposed `smoothExtentConstraint` which not work in my case. `smoothResolutionConstraint` did the work. Read carefully next time...

Comment: Yes, `smoothExtentConstraint` would only apply when trying to pan outside a defined extent, not zooming out beyond it.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski Ups, sorry. It's a looong option name, beginning and end is the same, so ... I upvoted your answer now (if that counts :-).

Comment: @TomazicM I posted an answer so that others could find answer quicker. Personal;y I don't care about points:)